# Lombok Annotations Not Detected In IntelliJ - Annotation Processing Enabled

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

I'm running IntelliJ IDEA and have installed the latest Lombok plugin as well as adding the dependency to my POM.  IntelliJ does not detect the Lombok annotations.  I have enabled annotation processing on my project and have also reinstalled the Lombok plugin but this does not seem to resolve the issue.  Any assistance is welcome

Comment: Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and specify your IntelliJ IDEA version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please update the Lombok plugin and restart IntelliJ.

After the IntelliJ update to 2018.2 the "two days old" Lombok-plugin does not work correctly. But shortly a patch to lombok was commited. After updating lombok everything worked fine for me again.

Comment: this seems to be true of upgrades to 2019.1.3 as well - once I updated the plugin everything started to work again.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by recreating my project.  It initially had been created using the Lombok Maven dependency generated by Spring Initializr.  In a separate project I added the latest Lombok Maven dependency and was able to use the annotations without a problem.  So I backed up the code, deleted the project and began a new one with the correct dependency.